# How to send WhatsApp DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I'm trying to send, to receive the envelope via WhatsApp.
I'm using SDK, with version 3.16.1 of docusign-esign-java, I'm putting

```
additionalNotification.setSecondaryDeliveryMethod("WhatsApp")
```

however, I am receiving the following error:

**EXError while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body: '{"errorCode":"ADDITIONAL_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NOT_SUPPORTED","message":"The Additional Notification channel is not supported. Envelope definition should not have additional notification channel: WhatsApp for recip 1"}'**

Comment: Does Docusign even *support* Whatsapp notifications? https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D58Z00008wOsdvSAC/can-i-send-a-docusign-form-link-on-whatsapp-to-my-clients-instead-of-directly-to-their-email?language=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my account was not enabled to send whatsapp and it was also sending the wrong parameters.

correct json:

```
"signers": [
    {
        "phoneNumber": {
            "countryCode": "{SIGNER_PHONE_COUNTRY}",
            "number": "{SIGNER_PHONE_NUMBER}"
        },
        "name": "{SIGNER_NAME}",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "deliveryMethod": "WhatsApp"
"tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [
                {
                    "anchorString": "**signature_1**",
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorXOffset": "20",
                    "anchorYOffset": "10"
                },
                {
                    "anchorString": "/sn1/",
                    "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                    "anchorXOffset": "20",
                    "anchorYOffset": "10"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign has publicly announced signing notifications via WhatsApp is on the roadmap. But the feature has not been released yet.
(this was true on Nov 9)

---

**This feature has since released,** see blog post - https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/whatsapp-joins-docusign-multi-channel-delivery

Code example - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-sms-whatsapp/

Comment: we are participating in BETA

Comment: Ask your Beta contact for help.